# Removing a specific class when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class from a div when the web browser is resized.. For example on a mobile device.

The line which I am trying to affect is

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="visitors">
```

I am trying to remove the `active` class. I have currently tried this:

```
$(window).on('load, resize', function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 600) {
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active").addClass("");
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to work though?

Comment: remove `,` from `load, resize`

Comment: You shouldn't check wiewport width using `$(window).width()`, see better alternative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the comma (`,`) between the event names - they should be separated with a space only.

Also note that there's no need to use `addClass('')`, your function name is redundant as it's an anonymous function, and you can use `toggleClass()` to simplify the logic and also make the class automatically be added/removed if the window is resized multiple times. Try this:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $(".tab-pane").toggleClass("active", $(window).width() >= 600);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yzrhm5y2/)

Resize the bottom right pane in the example above to see the code working.

Comment: For once beat you

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, the webpage is still appearing as though the class is still there.  Is the `.tab-pane` the right class to be selected?

Comment: @miotk this should work absolutely fine. The `.tab-pane` selector is correct.

Comment: @Satpal ;) ... although your comment has a lot of votes... should I be worried I have a reputation?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working whereas if I do actually remove the class from the line myself, it appears as though I want it to be but for desktop etc I need the active there.

Comment: @miotk I added a working example for you. If you're having issues check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, nope its just a banter. we developers can have fun sometime

Comment: @Satpal only while compiling

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I am compiling right now. cleaning up someone mess

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay, now it's working as such but it's making all of the divs with the `.tab-pane` appear active and listing everything inside of them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So hard to get fun for javascript devs... :)

Comment: @miotk That sounds like a separate issue with your HTML/CSS. All this code does is remove the class on `.tab-pane` elements

Comment: I've got it working, thanks @RoryMcCrossan I'll accept the answer as and when I can!

Comment: @A.Wolff — I wish we had something like [__`sleep`__](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php), we could have fun for little longer :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Only issue I have now is that the page loads up as normal and then it'll jump and they will be removed?

Comment: That's a side effect of using the `load` event on the window - as the code won't run until all content has loaded. A workaround would be to use a CSS media stylesheet to define the rules based on the resolution of the screen.

Comment: I am completely lost now as the jquery script src is interfering with plugins used on the site, without the script line then the site works fine but the code used here does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is right check here

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 600) {
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".tab-pane").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane active">a</div>
<div class="tab-pane active">a</div>
<div class="tab-pane active">a</div>
<div class="tab-pane active">a</div>
<div class="tab-pane active">a</div>
```

run it and resize it on another window